# Do you consider them as parenthetical phrases or adverbial phrases?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> We, **for our part**, **admitting the fact that no feat of
>   intelligence and character is so exacting as that required of two
>   people who desire to live permanently together on a basis of amity**,
>   are obsessed by the problem of how to render the basic facts of
>   cohabitation simpler and more reasonable, in order that unhappy
>   marriages may less frequently result.

For the two phrases "**for our part**" and "**admitting the fact ...amity**", does it make more sense to consider them as adverbial phrases than parenthetical phrases?

Comment: Parenthetical and adverbial are not necessarily incompatible. An adverbial phrase can be set off by commas and thus be parenthetical, as I think is the case with your examples above.

Comment: @Gustavson, I've been thinking an adverbial is kind of an "integrated" part of the sentence, whereas a parenthetical phrase is independent of the sentence. But that's just the way I differentiate them up to this point.

Comment: "parenthetical" is more related to punctuation, while "adverbial" is more related to syntax and meaning. I don't think those terms are mutually exclusive.